# how to mock file size with pathlib.Path objects?

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

In my function I was previously using the `os.path.getsize` function to get the file size.
So in my test suit I was using the following to test the resulting value of my function :

```py
# init test values
test_value = 7.5
size_name = ("B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB")
        
# mock 0 B file 
with patch('os.path.getsize', return_value=0):
    txt = su.get_file_size('random')
    self.assertEqual(txt, '0B')
        
# mock every pow of 1024 to YB
for i in range(9):
    with patch('os.path.getsize', return_value=test_value*(1024**i)):
        txt = su.get_file_size('random')
        self.assertEqual(txt, f'7.5 {size_name[i]}')
```

Now I internally use the `pathlib.Path` object as files. so I now want to mock `Path(filename).stat().st_size`. can someone tell me what I should use in my with statement instead of patch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you import `Path` using `from pathlib import Path` in your tested module, you could use something like this (check [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6) for more information):

```py
   with patch('yourmodule.su.Path.stat') as stat:
        stat.return_value.st_size = 0
        txt = get_file_size('random')
```

You cannot directly mock the whole expression because of the method call (`stat()`), which you have to mock using `return_value`, but it should be straightforward enough.